# Image Picker Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to create a website to show 6 images and a user can mark every image
he likes. Just like when you register on Netflix or the Captcha from Google.

I am very new to Web development and so I don't know what is the best way to do this. I created the website using Bootstrap but now I have trouble to implement the code to make the images checkable.

I found a very interesting plugin but it didn't work. But I am not sure if I implemented the plugin right. Link: http://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/

If I copy the code the images show up on the page but I cannot click them.

The code below is not my full website it's only a small page to test this.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='imgCheckbox/jquery.imgcheckbox.js'>
```

```
<body>
<!-- Main -->
<main role="main" class="container-fluid">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <section id="basicusage" class="wrapper special">
      <header class="major">
        <h2>Basic Usage</h2>
      </header>
      <form class="exampleone">
        <p>
          <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <span class="spacer"></span>
          <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <span class="spacer"></span>
          <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>

</main>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? Which part is not working as you intended? What did you expect it to do instead? Have you checked for errors on your browser's console?

Comment: I got the following error:jquery.imgcheckbox.js:381 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.imgcheckbox.js:381

Comment: You need to include jQuery if you want to use a jQuery plugin. Also, where is your javascript initializing the plugin?

Comment: At the end of the body I have the code for jUqery wich I copied from Bootstrap.I thought the line after head would initiaize the plugin

Comment: @Moschte Always import you framework **first** before you import the framework plugins. So move your `jquery.imgcheckbox.js` reference out of your head and put it **below** the jQuery import. Also, read the [usage section](https://github.com/jcuenod/imgCheckbox/) of the docs to see how to initialize the plugin -- hint it looks like this: `$("img.checkable").imgCheckbox();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since jquery.imgcheckbox is a **jquery** plugin, you need to include jquery.
This is done by linking to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js for example.
After jquery and the plugin have loaded successfully, you can add the checkbox to any image using **$("img").imgCheckbox();**

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("img").imgCheckbox();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/assets/js/jquery.imgcheckbox.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
  <section id="basicusage" class="wrapper special">
    <header class="major">
      <h2>Basic Usage</h2>
    </header>
    <form class="exampleone">
      <p>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        <span class="spacer"></span>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
      </p>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </section>
</div>
```

Please note, the above will just work here. Copy & paste won't work.
If you want something that can be saved as a .html file, take this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/assets/js/jquery.imgcheckbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function()
{
   $("img").imgCheckbox();
});
</script>
</head> 
  <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <section id="basicusage" class="wrapper special">
      <header class="major">
        <h2>Basic Usage</h2>
      </header>
      <form class="exampleone">
        <p>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <span class="spacer"></span>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          <span class="spacer"></span>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
</html>
```